# Page numbers > 99 in the table of content are not aligned correctly (cleanthesis)

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis, cleanthesis

How can I correctly align page numbers > 100 in the table of content? I use the `cleanthesis` template.

```
\documentclass[draft=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cleanthesis}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\blindtext[100]
\section{Section 2}
\blindtext[500]
\section{Section 3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you talking about [`cleanthesis.sty`](https://github.com/derric/cleanthesis/blob/master/cleanthesis.sty)? The page numbers in the ToC are right-aligned. How do you want them aligned?

Comment: Thx for your answer. Yep, its cleanthesis.sty. I want to right-align all numbers but page numbers > 100 are a little bit shifted to the right. It is indicated by a small black box in the example (draft=on). If you set draft=off, you will also notice the shift.

Comment: This is a zoomed image of the page numbers in the ToC obtained from your document (after removing xcolor): http://i.imgur.com/iV8Rgxc.png I don't see any shifting. Are you getting anything different with this same code?

Comment: @Kumar: With classicthesis.sty it works but I want to use cleanthesis.sty which is build on top of classicthesis.sty.

Comment: @Medina: Do you use cleanthesis.sty? With cleanthesis.sty you see the shifting: http://i.imgur.com/7uHEWd4.png. I guess the space reserved for the page numbers is to small. Is it possible to increase it?

Comment: The problem has something to do with the charter font. You find a solution here -> http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127643/fix-formatting-errors-of-page-number-99-in-table-of-contents