# Fix formatting errors of page number > 99 in table of contents?

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents

This is a follow up question of [Page numbers > 99 in the table of content are not aligned correctly (cleanthesis)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127049/page-numbers-99-in-the-table-of-content-are-not-aligned-correctly-cleanthesis). 
The formatting problem has nothing to do with cleanthesis.sty.

The problem is that if I use the charter font, page numbers greater than 99 are not formatted correctly in the table of content.

```
\documentclass[draft=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{charter}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section 1}
\blindtext[100]
\section{Section 2}
\blindtext[500]
\section{Section 3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the value for `\@pnumwidth` (the space reserved to typeset page numbers):

```
\documentclass[draft=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{charter}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@pnumwidth{2em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section 1}
\blindtext[100]
\section{Section 2}
\blindtext[500]
\section{Section 3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`scrbook.cls` has by default:

```
\newcommand*\@pnumwidth{1.55em}
```

Comment: Thx, you are the hero of my day!!!

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlength\mylen

\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~}
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylen}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[draft=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{charter}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newlength\mylen

\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{\chaptername~}
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\cftchappresnum\cftchapaftersnum}
\addtolength\cftchapnumwidth{\mylen}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section 1}
\blindtext[100]
\section{Section 2}
\blindtext[500]
\section{Section 3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to work with subfig.sty. The solution from Gonzalo works better. But anyway, thanks a lot for your time. I appreciate it!!!

Comment: @user4811 You have to load `subfig` after `tocloft`.