# Alignement in table of contents (\titlecontents)

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, titlesec, titletoc

In the code below, I use `\titlecontents{part}` to customise the way the parts are displayed in my table of contents.

```
\titlecontents{part}
              [0em]
              {\normalsize\bfseries\protect\addvspace{15pt}}%
              {\partname{} \thecontentslabel\brlap[\baselineskip]}%
              {}%
              {\enspace\titlerule\contentspage}%
```

For the moment, the result is as follows:

[image]

Can you help me to align the part label ("My first part", "My second part") to the left?

---

**Complete code**

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
 {\bfseries\Huge}
 {\partname{} \bfseries\thepart}
 {1ex}
 {}

\titlecontents{part}
              [0em]
              {\normalsize\bfseries\protect\addvspace{15pt}}%
              {\partname{} \thecontentslabel\brlap[\baselineskip]}
              {}%
              {\enspace\titlerule\contentspage}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{My first part}
\chapter{My first chapter}
\section{My first section}
\part{My second part}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with the packages you are using is to delay the printing of the part name and number to the end code:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 

\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
 {\bfseries\Huge}
 {\partname{} \bfseries\thepart}
 {1ex}
 {}

\titlecontents{part}
              [0em]
              {\normalsize\bfseries\protect\addvspace{15pt}}%
              {\brlap[\baselineskip]}
              {}%
              {\partname{} \thecontentslabel \enspace\titlerule\contentspage}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{My first part}
\chapter{My first chapter}
\section{My first section}
\part{My second part}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Inserting '\setcounter{page}{10000}' before '\part{My second part}', produces overfull hbox (at the part and at the section levels). Can you also help to sort that out ?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127643/15925.  `\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@pnumwidth{40pt}
\makeatother` will be more than sufficient.  Make sure you use `pt` not `em` here.

Comment: That works ! (+1)