# TOC Spacing between number and header

Tags: formatting

How do I increase the spacing between the subsection number and header name in the table of contents. I am using www.sharelatex.com.

When I have a large number of subsections the section numbers and headers overlap.

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{book}

% geometry sets paper dimensions
\usepackage[    paperheight=8in,
                paperwidth=6in,
                top=.1in,
                bottom=.2in,
                right=.1in,
                left=.1in,
                heightrounded]{geometry} 

% Font Style
\usepackage{bookman}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}

\end{document}
```

Edit: 12-22-2014
Found an answer to my question at [Roman numerals become “too wide” in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7415/roman-numerals-become-too-wide-in-table-of-contents)

I added these two lines to the preamble.

```
\usepackage[tocindentauto]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
```

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127643/fix-formatting-errors-of-page-number-99-in-table-of-contents/127652#127652

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Roman numerals become “too wide” in Table of Contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7415/5764)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the abovementioned link lacks a `titletoc` solution, here is one:

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{book}

% geometry sets paper dimensions
\usepackage[ paperheight=8in,
                paperwidth=6in,
                top=.1in,
                bottom=.2in,
                right=.1in,
                left=.1in,
                heightrounded]{geometry}

% Font Style
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\vspace{.25\baselineskip}}
{\eqparbox{ch}{\bfseries\thecontentslabel}\enspace}{}
{\hspace{.5em}\hfill\contentspage}

\titlecontents{section}[1.8em]{\vspace{.25\baselineskip}}
{{\thecontentslabel}\enspace}{}
{\hspace{.5em}\titlerule*[10pt]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}[4.5em]{\vspace{.25\baselineskip}}
{\eqparbox{Ss}{\thecontentslabel}\enspace}{}
{\hspace{.5em}\titlerule*[10pt]{$\cdot$}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsection{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]