# Latex table of content page number not contained in the margin

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I have a problem with the page number format in the table of contents. I'm using a thesis style derived from book.The screenshot below shows the problem. The page number "xxxi" is outside the margin box of the page. Any suggestions to fix this problem? I checked this answer [Fix formatting errors of page number > 99 in table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127643/fix-formatting-errors-of-page-number-99-in-table-of-contents), but it seems not fixing the issue.

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: we need a MWE to see where is the problem