Alignment issue in table of contents with more than 1000 pages
I help a student to write his PhD in LaTeX, and we face an issue regarding alignment. The Overfull \hbox (4.89952pt too wide) are highlighted below with black square in draft mode

It seems that the alignment of the pages is limited to 999 and when me exceed 1000 pages, there is an issue.
How could we fix this?
PS: I don't know how to provide a MWE with such an amount of pages, if someone knows, please feel free to help.

You could use \addtocounter{page}{1000} to create a MWE.

\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{2.5em} (or whatever width you want)

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127652/1090

Thanks to David Carlisle in the comments, following this link : tex.stackexchange.com/a/127652/1090 leads to this solution:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@pnumwidth{2.5em}
\makeatother


Depending on the class used, it might have an interface for that setting, but you gave no details. BTW out of curiosity, what is that student writing about, since it is now above 1k pages

This is the appendix containing the corpus of 600 letters (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lettre_de_naturalit%C3%A9)
